# How to replace libapt-private.so.0.0.0 manually on Ubuntu for Windows?

Tags: apt, bash, permissions, windows

I'm using Ubuntu for Windows, and have been for some time. `/etc/debian_version` names it as `buster/sid`. As a result of recent suspected disk corruption, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0.0` appears to have been replaced by a same-sized file containing only (binary) zeroes.

This breaks `apt` and prevents its self-repair, of course.

I have been given a copy of the same file by colleagues. However, I cannot find a way to replace the one in my filesystem. Even launching `bash` with Windows Administrator privileges, and then acquiring root privileges within that shell, does not permit me to rename or replace the file.

It's highly discouraged to attempt to alter these files from Windows tools such as File Explorer and the `cmd` shell - however, even running `cmd` with Administrator privileges gives "`Access is denied.`"

How can I replace this library file under Ubuntu for Windows? Is it even possible? Google and StackExchange searches have not been helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101973/discussion-between-jon-green-and-malte-skoruppa).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101982/discussion-on-question-by-jon-green-how-to-replace-libapt-private-so-0-0-0-manua).

Comment: Think it was Windows Defender that broke mine in the same manner today by quarantining this library.

Comment: See this thread https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4745. The issue has been fixed internally at Microsoft.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, my WSL got broken because of Windows Defender detecting my `libapt-private.so.0.0.0` as a trojan. [*insert ironic comment here*]

(*UPDATE: This SO answer reports some [news from Microsoft on the issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194809/1023833)*)

#### Solution

First of all, the most annoying thing was that every attempt to delete or move the library gave "Permission Denied" error. In order to prevent this, make sure you are operating as Administrator: **open your WSL shell from an elevated cmd/powershell** and work there.

*What follows is (almost) the implementation of `Imaginecat22`'s answer.*

1. **Find your version of `apt`**

   ```
   $ dpkg -l apt

   [. . .]
   ||/ Name                              Version               Architecture          Description
   +++-=================================-=====================-=====================-=======================================================================
   ii  apt                               1.6.11                amd64                 commandline package manager
   ```

   write down the value of `Architecture`.
2. **Download `.deb` package**

   Most packages can be found with the [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apt).

   Not all versions are available there though, so you may need to download manually:

   - use a web browser to open:

     `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/<VERSION>/`

     Replace `<VERSION>` with the value of `Version` returned in step 1, e.g.:

     https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/1.6.11/
   - Find the **Builds** section and select the build that matches the `Architecture` value from step 1.

   Copy the URL to download the file `apt_<VERSION>_<ARCHITECTURE>.deb`. From your WSL Linux shell download the package:

   ```
       $ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/1.6.11/+build/16829590/+files/apt_1.6.11_amd64.deb
   ```
3. **Install package using dpkg**

   ```
   $ dpkg -i apt_1.6.11_amd64.deb
   ```

Should overwrite your previous version and the broken library with it.

Comment: Thanks, Salvioner, but (as I've noted elsewhere) when I use dpkg to install the .deb, I get "`unable to make backup link of './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0.0' before installing new version: Permission denied`". That's using `sudo` for the `dpkg` command, and even from within a `bash` window launched with Windows Administrator permissions. (Or from `bash` invoked from a `cmd` shell launched with Windows Administrator permissions.)

Comment: OK, I'm going to facepalm now, because I missed the bit about Windows Defender. When I _did_ notice it, I went into Defender, noted it had quarantined the file, and marked it for removal. It wasn't actually removed until I'd rebooted. Then I could copy a known good version into place, and all's now good. Thanks!

Comment: You need to be root to run `dpkg -i`. The last command should be `dpkg -i apt_1.6.11_amd64.deb`

Comment: @JonGreen that's weird, I just needed to open `cmd` as an Admin to fix the backup link issue. Or at least, I managed (after making a backup `cp` of the library) to remove the file, after that the installation completed successfully.

Comment: @JonGreen kinda interesting the fact that Defender requires to reboot the PC to remove the detected file. Is a reboot required also for restoring files? Because I tried simply to ignore the file from the Defender UI, but it completely ignored all my attempts to remove or restore it. It never says to reboot, but maybe that's exactly what I should have done.

Comment: @Shoan Unless other distros work differently, on Ubuntu WSL you are root user by default...

Answer (score 1):

My Windows Defender just removed my sudo_libutil.so.0.0.0.
I managed to fix the problem without reinstalling any packages.

I posted the answer to superuser.com [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1508901/windows-defender-just-removed-sudo-on-my-debian-wsl-can-i-restore-this/1508936#1508936)

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into the same problem. Just get yourself a new apt.deb package and manually reinstall it with dpkg -i

I got mine from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt

Then run apt update, upgrade, probably fix-broken, etc.

Comment: Thanks @crisdias - unfortunately, I'd tried that without success - got a bunch of errors I listed in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101982/discussion-on-question-by-jon-green-how-to-replace-libapt-private-so-0-0-0-manua but tl;dr is that it threw permission errors when trying to replace that file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having exactly the same problem - to the point where I was watching your discussion and following along. 
I created a Stack Overflow account just to let you know I figured it out! (This is my first post lol)
**The trick is to install (or like me have installed) WSL on another machine**, then scp the libapt-private.so.0.0.0 file over straight to the directory!

After that, I typed sudo apt-get -f install and it ran like normal :)
Hope this helps!